# Return Blank instead of FALSE in IF formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In the formula if `AT6` is not equal to `1` then it should return `blank` but it is returning `FALSE`.

**Formula-** `IF(AT6=1,IF(C6="Plat",VLOOKUP(),IF(C6="SOR",VLOOKUP(),"")))`

Comment: `IF(AT6=1,IF(C6="Plat",VLOOKUP(),IF(C6="SOR",VLOOKUP(),"")),"")`

Comment: You didnt have a return for the false part of your formula where AT6=1, so as @ScottCraner shows.